# Let f: R->R be a continuous function satisfying Cauchy's equation.

Tags: functions

Let f: R->R be a continuous function satisfying Cauchy's equation. Suppose in addition that there exists some interval [c,d] of real numbers, where c < d, such that f bounded below on [c,d].

a) Show that f(nx)=nf(x) for all real x.

b) Define p=d-c. Show that f is bounded below on the interval [0,p]. (However, it need not be bounded below by the same constant as on interval [c,d])

c) Define the function:
g(x)=f(x)-$\dfrac{f(p)}{p}x$. Prove that g is also bounded below on the interval [0,p] and satisfies Cauchy's equation.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Your question is phrased without any information or context. This does not 
match [users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it will most likely attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To 
prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This link](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve 
the issues. For some basic information about writing math on MSE see 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Please, help me!!

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

a) Use induction. Recall that Cauchy equation means $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$.

b) $f$ is continous. $[0,p]$ is compact. You should be able to conclude something.

c) check that $g$ is continuous, $[0,p]$ is compact, what can you conclude?

$$g(x+y)=f(x+y)-\frac{f(p)}{p}(x+y)=f(x)-\frac{f(p)}{p}x+f(y)-\frac{f(p)}{p}y$$

Comment: I still do not understand, f bounded below on [c,d] for what? Thank you :)

Comment: hmmm... why must we use all the information that is given to us?